# Show something while data is being searched on databse

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, loading

I want to show a gif while the user's username and password are being validated, but my ajax code isn't storing the submited data, then nothing happens.

login.php (where the inputs are)

```
          <div>  
            <input type="text" class="css-input" placeholder="Insira seu código" required="" name="codigo" style="background: url(images/icons/user_o.png) no-repeat scroll 5px 5px; background-size: 25px; background-color: #FFFFFF;color: #FF5400;"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="password" class="css-input" placeholder="Senha" required="" name="senha" style="background: url(images/icons/pwd.png) no-repeat scroll 5px 5px; background-size: 25px;"/>
          </div>
```

login2 (validation form)

```
        <?php
        $codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['codigo']); 
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']); 

        $sql_codigo = "SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_codigo = '$codigo'";
        $sql_nome = "SELECT usu_nome FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_codigo = '$codigo'";

        $sql_nome_resul = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql_nome);
        $coluna_bd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_nome_resul);

        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql_codigo);
         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
         {
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
              if(password_verify($senha, $row['usu_senha']))  
              {  
                $_SESSION['codigo']=$codigo;
                echo '<p><span style="font-family: calibri, sans-serif;"><span style="color: #a1eb8f; font-size: 17pt;">Ol&aacute; ' . $coluna_bd['usu_nome'] . '! Aguarde um instante...</span></span></p>';  
                $response['type'] = 'success';
              }  
              else  
              {  
                echo '<p><span style="font-family: calibri, sans-serif; color: #ff8f57;"><span style="font-size: 17pt;">Usu&aacute;rio e/ou senha incorretos!</span></span></p>';
                $response['type'] = 'failure';
              }
              echo json_encode($response);
            }
          } 
        ?>
```

javascript.js (ajax not working)

```
$("#login").click(function(){


  $.get("login2.php", {codigo: codigo, senha: senha}, function(data){
    if (data.type == "success"){
      window.location = "index.php";
    }
    else{
      window.location = "login.php";
    }
  }, "JSON"); 
});
```

So, I didn't actually made the gif part yet because I'm trying to at least go through this part, but without success so far.

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you define and set values for the ajax parameters `{codigo: codigo, senha: senha}`?

Comment: Why are you making `get` request via ajax and in the server you try to fetch them from `$_POST`?

Comment: This code is not safe against [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), better to use prepared statements and much safer than `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @AlonEitan oh, so, I think I should do the validation right in the first form to get via ajax?

Comment: I know, gonna work prepared statements after correcting this

Comment: To get the values you need the following selector `{ codigo: $('input[name="codigo"]').val(), senha: $('input[name="senha"]').val() }`

Comment: And this is what you need to read in order to make your code secure against SQL injection: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @AlonEitan didn't work, I tried to use just one form as login and validation, but unlucky